Snowflake cli error Invalid connection configuration. 250001: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 2 attempt(s).Aborting
I am trying to connect to snowflake using snowflake cli. I have configured toml file where I have saved all the connection details as shown below. but i am continiously getting error "Invalid connection configuration. 250001: 250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 2 attempt(s).Aborting"


Instead of uploading screenshot of your source code, provide the source code itself with sensitive data removed.

Are you sure your account name/identifier is correct ?
It looks like your account name/identifier is wrong.
You are using hyphen in account name, which is not supported for SQl operations.
Account Identifier
You can try out two versions, format1 and format2.
Format 1
Format 1: organization name + account name in <orgname>.<account_name> format.
GIWUXYZ.ANALYTICS_ADVISOR_UK


Pay attention, orgname and account name are joined using dot, not a hyphen or underscore character.

orgname-account_name (for most URLs and other general purpose usage, including Snowflake drivers)
orgname-account-name (for scenarios/features where underscores in an account name are not supported)
orgname.account_name (for SQL commands and operations)

How to get the Orgname and account name on Snowsight:


Open the account selector and review the list of accounts that you previously signed in to.



Locate the account for which you want to copy the account name.

Hover over the account to view additional details, and then select the copy icon to copy the account identifier in the format orgname.account_name to your clipboard.




source

Format 2
If you have any accounts that existed before the Organizations feature was enabled, the Format 2: Account locator in a region is used as the account name.
the Format 2: consists of three parts:  account locator, region, and cloud provider.
example:
xy12345.us-east-2.aws
xy12345.us-east4.gcp
xy12345.east-us-2.azure

You can find it in the url  bar of the Snowsight.
Change your account identifier and give it another go.

not working I changed account to "dh81341.central-india.azure" but still it is showing me the same error

@AnshumanSrivastava I have updated my answer, give it another try, please

I believe it should be deined in connections.toml rather than config.toml, see my below walkthrough
this is what i wrote to myself with regards to snowflake native apps, for future maybe it will be helpful for you

you're supposed to use snowflakecli ( not snowsql ) the command for snowflake cli is "snow" rather than "snowsql" that is used above, not confusing at all right?
for "snow" to work you have to install it and use it in windows in command prompt started as admin
once it's working you have configure it, the way to do this is
issue $ snow connection list
go to the connection file it lists
add your configs in the .toml file the same way other look like ( all see my config below )
issue snow connection set-default  (myconnection)
test it by running snow sql --query "select 'this is not painful at all snowflake team' as is_it_painful "
now you should be able to issue snow app run as the walkthrough tells you to do

connection.toml file
["myconnection"]
name = "your_cute_name_not_the_same_as_myconnection_above_which_is_the_real_name"
account = "dagass-graawa"
user = "MAGA47"
authenticator = "snowflake"
password = "will_not_tell_you"

